# What is the countable dense in $2^\mathfrak{c}$.

Tags: general-topology

As we know that $2^\mathfrak{c}$ is separable, but I wonder what is the countable dense that makes $2^\mathfrak{c}$ separable.

The only thing I know is the product of separable space up to $\mathfrak{c}$ is still separable and each finite discrete is separable.

Any idea.

Comment: If you **know** that the product of continuum many separable spaces is separable, then you must know a proof of that fact. Apply that proof to the case you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\mathfrak c$ to be $[0,1]$ (or any other set with cardinal $\mathfrak c$ you like). Then $2^{[0,1]}=\left\{f:[0,1]\to\{0,1\}\right\}$. And a neighborhood of $f\in2^{[0,1]}$ contains all $g:[0,1]\to\{0,1\}$ such that, at finitely many given points in $[0,1]$, $g$ must take the same value as $f$.

Now let $A\subset2^{[0,1]}$ contains all functions whose graph consists of finitely many horizontal segments with rational endpoints. Then $A$ is countable. It remains to show that for all $f\in 2^{[0,1]}$, all neighborhoods of $f$ intersect $A$. This is easy because we have known what the neighborhoods look like.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\c{\mathfrak{c}}$First, a point of $2^\c$ is the same thing as a set $A ⊆ \c$. There are many subsets of $\c$ but you don't need all of them to get a dense set in $2^\c$, you just need a system $\mathcal{A} ⊆ \mathcal{P}(\c)$ such that for every finite sets $F_1, F_2 ⊆ \c$ there is $A ∈ \mathcal{A}$ such that $F_1 ⊆ A$ and $A ∩ F_2 = ∅$. To find such system, view $\c$ as $2^ω$. So it is enough to define $\mathcal{A}$ as a coutable basis of $2^ω$.

So a countable dense set of $2^\c$ is a countable basis of $\c$ viewed as $2^ω$.